# JSP: SAXParseException - Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, jsp

I want to parse an xml file using the following jsp script:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory" %>
<%@ page import="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder" %>
<%@ page import="org.xml.sax.SAXParseException" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.File" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputSource" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.StringReader" %>
<%@ page import="org.w3c.dom.Document" %>
<%
try
{
    String xmlFileURI = "test\\foo.xml";
    File file = new File (xmlFileURI);
    if (file.exists ())
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance ();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder ();
        InputSource is = new InputSource (new StringReader (xmlFileURI));
        Document document = builder.parse (is);
    }
}
catch (IOException ioEx)
{
    out.println ("<p>");
    out.println("IOException: " + ioEx.getMessage ());
}
catch (SAXParseException saxEx)
{
    out.println ("<p>");
    out.println("SAXParseException: " + saxEx);
}
%>
```

However, the line with

```
builder.parse (is);
```

always throws this exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

I found that lots of other people ran into that issue already, but they mostly seem to be caused by having BOM in their xml file. I printed out the hex values of the file, it starts out with

> 3c 3f 78 6d 20 76 etc.

so it looks fine to me.

My xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar>asdf</bar>
    <foobar>asdf</foobar>
</foo>
```

and is located in `C:\Tomcat8.0\test`. I also tried using an absolute path for `xmlFileURI`, but with the same results.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like Java `StringReader` accepts string, *not URI* to a file which content will be read as string. So in this case, your code passes value "test\\foo.xml" to `builder.parse()` instead of passing string content of `foo.xml` file, hence the error.

Comment: How about `builder.parse(file)`? http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Nope, `builder.parse(file)` results in the same exception.

Comment: Hold on, `builder.parse(file)` DOES work! I didn't realize I had to restart Tomcat for that. Thank you!

Comment: Great you solved it! I converted my comment to answer so this question can be closed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Java `StringReader` accepts string, *not URI* to a file which content will be read as string. So in this case, your code passes value "test\foo.xml" to `builder.parse()` instead of passing string content of 'foo.xml' file, hence the error.

That said, use `builder.parse(file)`* instead :

```
String xmlFileURI = "test\\foo.xml";
File file = new File (xmlFileURI);
if (file.exists ())
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(file);
}
```

*) Not a Java programmer, got the idea from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/). And don't forget to restart Tomcat, as OP mentioned, for this changes to take effect.